# dungeon problem using dp recursive approach

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

This is the Question...
The following problems revolve around an adventurer who enters a dungeon in search of Gold
(Treasure). The objective for all the questions will be to find the quickest path to the Gold
without bringing harm to the adventurer. In each question, we will edit or bring in new elements
to the dungeon (an underground prison cell). Your task is to find the shortest path for the
adventurer to get the Gold which can be located anywhere in the dungeon. (The location of the
Gold will be given in the input).
In each turn the adventurer (the person who goes to get the gold in the dungeon) can move
one step (right, left, up, down). A single cell can be occupied by both adventurer and Gold
(i.e. any number of items can be available in a cell)
A monster (M) will be introduced in the dungeon. The monster's aim is to prevent the adventurer
from getting the gold. It will move in the best way possible to achieve this (i.e. if the monster can
reach gold before the adventurer, then the monster can prevent the adventurer from getting
gold). The monster will move only after the adventurer makes his move.
Note:-

1. The monster may or may not move every turn (every time the adventurer moves).
2. Both the monster and the adventurer know each other's location.
   Task: To find the minimum no of moves, so that the adventurer can reach the gold without dying.

Sample Input 1:
Dimensions of the dungeon(Row x Column): 5 4
Position of adventurer: 4 1
Position of monster: 3 1
Position of gold: 2 3
Sample Output 1:
No possible solution
Sample Input 2:
Dimensions of the dungeon(Row x Column): 5 4
Position of adventurer: 5 1
Position of monster: 3 1
Position of gold: 4 3
Sample Output 2:
Minimum number of steps: 3

I tried dp  recursive approach but i don't know what went wrong? for some input i am getting stackoverflow error and for some input i am not getting correct output. Here's my code below in JAVA.

package sample;

//Online Java Compiler

//Use this editor to write, compile and run your Java code online
import java.util.*;

```
public class HelloWorld {
public static int findminstep(int m, int n, int a1, int a2, int m1, int m2, int g1, int g2, int[][][][]       dp) {
    if (a1 < 0 || a2 < 0 || m1 < 0 || m2 < 0 || a1 >= m || m1 >= m || a2 >= n || m2 >= n) {
        return (int) Math.pow(10, 8);
    }

    if (a1 == g1 && a2 == g2) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (a1 == m1 && a2 == m2) {
        return (int) Math.pow(10, 8);
    }

    if (m1 == g1 && m2 == g2) {
        return (int) Math.pow(10, 8);
    }

    if (dp[a1][a2][m1][m2] != -1) {
        return dp[a1][a2][m1][m2];
    }

    int aa = 1 + findminstep(m, n, a1 - 1, a2, m1, m2, g1, g2, dp);
    int ab = 1 + findminstep(m, n, a1, a2 + 1, m1, m2, g1, g2, dp);
    int ac = 1 + findminstep(m, n, a1 + 1, a2, m1, m2, g1, g2, dp);
    int ad = 1 + findminstep(m, n, a1, a2 - 1, m1, m2, g1, g2, dp);
    int amin = Math.min(Math.min(aa, ab), Math.min(ac, ad));

    int ma = 1 + findminstep(m, n, a1 - 1, a2, m1 - 1, m2, g1, g2, dp);
    int mb = 1 + findminstep(m, n, a1 - 1, a2, m1, m2 + 1, g1, g2, dp);
    int mc = 1 + findminstep(m, n, a1 - 1, a2, m1 + 1, m2, g1, g2, dp);
    int md = 1 + findminstep(m, n, a1 - 1, a2, m1, m2 - 1, g1, g2, dp);

    int me = 1 + findminstep(m, n, a1, a2 + 1, m1 - 1, m2, g1, g2, dp);
    int mf = 1 + findminstep(m, n, a1, a2 + 1, m1, m2 + 1, g1, g2, dp);
    int mg = 1 + findminstep(m, n, a1, a2 + 1, m1 + 1, m2, g1, g2, dp);
    int mh = 1 + findminstep(m, n, a1, a2 + 1, m1, m2 - 1, g1, g2, dp);

    int mi = 1 + findminstep(m, n, a1 + 1, a2, m1 - 1, m2, g1, g2, dp);
    int mj = 1 + findminstep(m, n, a1 + 1, a2, m1, m2 + 1, g1, g2, dp);
    int mk = 1 + findminstep(m, n, a1 + 1, a2, m1 + 1, m2, g1, g2, dp);
    int ml = 1 + findminstep(m, n, a1 + 1, a2, m1, m2 - 1, g1, g2, dp);

    int mm = 1 + findminstep(m, n, a1, a2 - 1, m1 - 1, m2, g1, g2, dp);
    int mn = 1 + findminstep(m, n, a1, a2 - 1, m1, m2 + 1, g1, g2, dp);
    int mo = 1 + findminstep(m, n, a1, a2 - 1, m1 + 1, m2, g1, g2, dp);
    int mp = 1 + findminstep(m, n, a1, a2 - 1, m1, m2 - 1, g1, g2, dp);
    int bmin1 = Math.min(Math.min(ma, mb), Math.min(mc, md));
    int bmin2 = Math.min(Math.min(me, mf), Math.min(mg, mh));
    int bmin3 = Math.min(Math.min(mi, mj), Math.min(mk, ml));
    int bmin4 = Math.min(Math.min(mm, mn), Math.min(mo, mp));

    int bmin = Math.min(Math.min(bmin1, bmin2), Math.min(bmin3, bmin4));

    int res = Math.min(amin, bmin);
    dp[a1][a2][m1][m2] = res;

    return res;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int m, n, a1, a2, m1, m2, g1, g2;
    System.out.println("Enter rows:");
    m = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Column");
    n = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Adventurer Position:");
    a1 = scan.nextInt();
    a2 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Monster Position");
    m1 = scan.nextInt();
    m2 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Gold Position");
    g1 = scan.nextInt();
    g2 = scan.nextInt();
    int dp[][][][] = new int[m][n][m][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < n; l++) {
                    dp[i][j][k][l] = -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int result = findminstep(m, n, a1, a2, m1, m2, g1, g2, dp);

    if (result == (int) Math.pow(10, 8)) {
        System.out.println("No possible solution");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Minimum number of steps: " + result);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution appears to be on the right track, but it is always important to keep an eye open for errors such as StackOverflow due to how you terminate the recursive calls inefficiently.

I would first replace the Math.pow(10, 8) with Integer.MAX_VALUE for representing infinity.

```
if (a1 < 0 || a2 < 0 || m1 < 0 || m2 < 0 || a1 >= m || m1 >= m || a2 >= n || m2 >= n) {
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

Then change the way you handle adventurer and monster movements by considering their positions separately.

```
int[] dx = {-1, 1, 0, 0};
int[] dy = {0, 0, -1, 1};
int minSteps = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int newA1 = a1 + dx[i];
    int newA2 = a2 + dy[i];

    int newM1 = m1;
    int newM2 = m2;

    if (newA1 == newM1 && newA2 == newM2) {
        // If adventurer and monster collide, the monster doesnt move
        newM1 = m1;
        newM2 = m2;
    } else {
        // Monster tries to move closer to adventurer
        int dxMonster = (a1 - m1) > 0 ? 1 : (a1 - m1) < 0 ? -1 : 0;
        int dyMonster = (a2 - m2) > 0 ? 1 : (a2 - m2) < 0 ? -1 : 0;
        newM1 = m1 + dxMonster;
        newM2 = m2 + dyMonster;
    }

    int steps = 1 + findMinSteps(m, n, newA1, newA2, newM1, newM2, g1, g2, dp);
    minSteps = Math.min(minSteps, steps);
}
```

I would also modify the input indices to be 0-based since all arrays in Java follow this conventionally.

```
int result = findMinSteps(m, n, a1 - 1, a2 - 1, m1 - 1, m2 - 1, g1 - 1, g2 - 1, dp);
```

After adding all the stuff above with the rest together:

```
import java.util.*;

public class DungeonSolver {
    public static int findMinSteps(int m, int n, int a1, int a2, int m1, int m2, int g1, int g2, int[][][][] dp) {
        if (a1 < 0 || a2 < 0 || m1 < 0 || m2 < 0 || a1 >= m || m1 >= m || a2 >= n || m2 >= n) {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        if (a1 == g1 && a2 == g2) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (a1 == m1 && a2 == m2) {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        if (dp[a1][a2][m1][m2] != -1) {
            return dp[a1][a2][m1][m2];
        }

        int[] dx = {-1, 1, 0, 0};
        int[] dy = {0, 0, -1, 1};
        int minSteps = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            int newA1 = a1 + dx[i];
            int newA2 = a2 + dy[i];

            int newM1 = m1;
            int newM2 = m2;

            if (newA1 == newM1 && newA2 == newM2) {
                newM1 = m1;
                newM2 = m2;
            } else {
                int dxMonster = (a1 - m1) > 0 ? 1 : (a1 - m1) < 0 ? -1 : 0;
                int dyMonster = (a2 - m2) > 0 ? 1 : (a2 - m2) < 0 ? -1 : 0;
                newM1 = m1 + dxMonster;
                newM2 = m2 + dyMonster;
            }

            int steps = 1 + findMinSteps(m, n, newA1, newA2, newM1, newM2, g1, g2, dp);
            minSteps = Math.min(minSteps, steps);
        }

        dp[a1][a2][m1][m2] = minSteps;
        return minSteps;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int m, n, a1, a2, m1, m2, g1, g2;
        System.out.println("Enter rows:");
        m = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Column");
        n = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Adventurer Position:");
        a1 = scan.nextInt();
        a2 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Monster Position");
        m1 = scan.nextInt();
        m2 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Gold Position");
        g1 = scan.nextInt();
        g2 = scan.nextInt();
        int[][][][] dp = new int[m][n][m][n];

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < n; l++) {
                        dp[i][j][k][l] = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        int result = findMinSteps(m, n, a1 - 1, a2 - 1, m1 - 1, m2 - 1, g1 - 1, g2 - 1, dp);

        if (result == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            System.out.println("No possible solution");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Minimum number of steps: " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering but still i am getting wrong answer for some inputs like if there are 2 rows and 3 columns and adventurer pos is 0,1 gold pos is 0,2 but the monster pos is 1,0. here the answer should be 1 as the gold is present in the very next position of adventurer but it shows no possible solution and also i am still getting stack overflow exception for 5*4 matrix.